# How can I add banner slider on my home page?

Tags: frontend

I want to add slider on my home page. How can I add slider?

Comment: In Craft, you as developer are responsible for everything that is front-end. So if you want a banner slider, you'll have to add a field on the entry where you can add images, and in your entry's template, write the needed html to display the banner.

Comment: Okay.Is there any demo of slider website?

Comment: I'd suggest just going trough the documentation (https://craftcms.com/docs/introduction) , also you could check out the courses at mijngo (https://mijingo.com/craft) but those aren't free

Comment: @MichaelRosmane you should post that as an official answer, where you might also want to add a link to the Flickity or Slick documentation.

Comment: @carlcs Done, thansk for the tip...

Answer (score 4):

In Craft, you as developer are responsible for everything that is front-end output. So if you want a banner slider, you'll have to add a field on the entry where you can add images, and in your entry's template, write the needed html to display the banner.

I'd suggest going trough the [documentation](http://craftcms.com/docs/introduction) to learn about entries, fields,templates, ... Also you could check out the courses at for example [mijngo](http://mijingo.com/craft) but those aren't free.

As carlcs pointed out, here are some popular options for displaying banners:

- [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)
- [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Can I use wordpress theme in craft cms?

Comment: Actually my site is in wordpress and I want to migrate it on Craft cms.

Comment: You won't be able to use a Wordpress theme, well not without making heavy modifications to it. There might be ways to migrate the data from Wordpress to a Craft site, but for the templates, there's no real way to convert them, as Craft has a completely different way of using templates.

Comment: One could grab the output HTML and CSS from a single blog page and use that as a base for the Twig template. You should probably check the theme’s license before doing so.